# When a user imports the schema or sample data set from database into the HCL OneTest Data project then will the views also get imported?

Tags: import, view, schema

While using HCL OneTest Data, if I import a schema or sample data set from any database then will the views also get imported?

Answer (score 0):

HCL OneTest Data does not support to import the schema or sample data set from the database. HCL OneTest Data generates schema from tables or views available in the database.